# Java: Calling an interface's function from a Generic List that Extends it

Tags: java, generics, arraylist, interface

I want to have a list of objects that all inherit from the same interface that contains the function go().

```
public interface goers{
    public void go();
}
```

Now I have 3 classes that all implement go, for the sake of simplicity let's just call them A, B, and C.

In another class I have a `List<Class<? extends goers>>` that I want to do.

```
for (Class<? extends goers> gos : list)
    {
        gos.go();
    }
```

But it won't compile because the compiler doesn't pick up the go method from the interface being applied to all of the members of the list.

Comment: Do you have a `List<goers>`, or a `List<Class<? extends goers>>`?  It matters.  (The second one you can't call `.go()` on, the first one you can.)

Comment: Updates the question, it's the second one.

Comment: You should follow the Java naming conventions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A `List<Class<? extends goers>>` doesn't have a `goers` instance that you can call `.go()` on. You just have classes, not any instances of that classes. There's nothing to call `.go()` on.

You could try instantiating those classes, or having a `List<goers>` in the first place, which lets you call it how interfaces are intended to be used.

Comment: @Andreas that's what I meant by "try instantiating those classes."

Comment: Yeah, I was writing that before you added the second paragraph. My intent was for you to show example of it too. ;-)

Comment: Thanks, My brain completely whiffed and thought you couldn't have an interface as the type of a list and caused all my issues.  I'll accept this answer once I can.

Answer (score 2):

Because `go()` is not a method of `Class<T>`, you cannot call that method on an instance of `Class<T>`. You have to use only methods of https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html.

If you want an instance of `goers` [sic - follow the naming conventions] you need to get one somehow. You could use, for example, https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#newInstance--.

Your essential problem is that you're using reflection, an advanced technique that is easy to abuse and hard to get right. Why don't you pass a list of instances of `goers` [sic - follow the naming conventions] instead of `Class` objects?

Comment: The OP is not (currently) using reflection.

Comment: `List<Class<? extends goers>>` is reflection.